# Adding browser size query to supersize plugin javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am using the supersize slideshow plugin. When the browser size reaches a certain minimum size I want to deactivate this part of the script to prevent the image from centring:

```
// Adjust image when browser is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
base.resizeNow();
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the viewport dimensions of your page, and then wrap your resize function inside an if statement:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{

    var currentViewPortHeight = $( window ).height();
    var currentViewPortWidth = $( window ).width();
    var minimumViewPortHeight = 100 //your minimum height;
    var minimumViewPortWidth = 100 // your minimum width;

    if(currentViewPortHeight > minimumViewPortHeight && currentViewPortWidth > minimumViewPortWidth )
    {
        base.resizeNow();
    }
});
```